# Tranforming single-customer web application into a multi-customer application

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, webapp2

We've developed a web application (PHP & Mysql) which is currently single-customer, i.e the users, with different permission levels, are all part of the same company and thus have access to the same data. 
We are now planning to transform it into a multi-customer platform, meaning different set of users must access different sets of data.

The obvious way is to separate the data by adding a "owner" column to all the MySql tables which contain customers data. The hard part is changing all the PHP code to take the extra parameter into account. 
Our idea is to pre-filter the data by the "owner" column so that all further interrogation queries will always and only select the data relative to the connected customer. In this way we don't have to change every single query in our code (table names in queries are already parameterized).
Can this be done using temporary tables? We have a custom PHP class that handles all the database queries and oour thought was to make it replicate the data of the connected customer in temporary tables every time the class object is created. Interrogation queries will be automatically routed to the temp tables instead of the original tables, while insert, update and delete operations will be performed on the original. Is this a feasible method or will we running into trouble? Performance is of course an issue here. 
Any other suggestions on how to handle this?

### EDIT

Further information: The login and authentication of the users is handled by PHP, which sets several session variables regarding the account. The user accounts are stored in a 'user' table in the same database where the data the user will interrogate / edit is stored.
So after login we have a the variable **$_SESSION['owner']** that will be available throughout the project and will be used to identify the records the user can see/edit.

Comment: Depending on the type of application (and clients) it is good to provide data isolation, eg separate databases for each client. You write that you have parameterized table names. You can use subqueries `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM org_tbl WHERE owner = 'aa') as tbl`, although the performance of queries will fall a lot. Accept that you have to rewrite all queries. (And mark those patched up so that it does not add a filter subquery)

Comment: The number of clients is variable and hopefully high, so I would exclude data isolation. Rewriting all queries would of course be our last resort. Are temporary tables better/worse than subqueries performance-wise?

Comment: Temporary tables - It depends on how much data you will put in temporary tables. Using subqueries will be the fastest way. So you can start changing the most frequently used queries faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you require the user to login using the "user" value, you can build a join table with owner and user (and I like to add an active flag, just for s&g).  There really isn't a good way to add temp tables or views because every "owner" will have a view.  There is sort of a solution.  You can create a view based on the table that joins to the "owner" table on user(). So, for example, if I have a table called usertemp(user varchar(40), owner varchar(45)) and my username is 'biff' (and it exists in the table), I can build a view:

```
create view usertemp_v
as
select user, owner
from usertemp
where user=user();
```

I can then query the view:

```
select *
from usertemp_v;
```

All I will see is the data that has my name associated with it.  Please understand, though, that it requires that you either set a variable for the user or that the users have individual logins to MySQL.  It also requires that the permissions (IP address or domain) also be present in the owner_users table (if using user()).

I then have to join against your main source tables for the owner that I join to in usertemp.

Comment: I don't really understand the user=user() part in the view. What does user() refer to?

Comment: In the table, there is a column called "user".  In mysql there is also a function to return the current session user "user()".  In essence, I am matching the user in the "virtual private row" to the currently logged in user account.  This is a general guide.  If your software requires a different method to identify a given user, you can substitute it (like @user variable).